# God promises David that his kingdom will endure forever, then why did Israel's throne become empty for nearly 600 years before Jesus?

Tags: israel, david, promises

Some relevant texts: [2 Samuel 7:12-16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20samuel%207&version=ESV), [2 Chronicles 13:5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20chronicles%2013&version=ESV), [Psalm 89:20-37](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=psalms%2089&version=ESV), [1 Kings 11:36](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20kings%2011&version=ESV), etc.

It seems that God promises David a *continuous* Davidic line on the throne, without interruption (especially the text in [Jeremiah 33:17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=jeremiah%2033&version=ESV)). But this didn't happen because before Jesus' birth, the Davidic line was interrupted with Zedekiah, leaving a near 600-year gap between Zedekiah and Jesus unexplained.

How should we interpret God's promise then?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Comment: Jesus from line of David rules God’s kingdom forever

Comment: You seem to interpret Jeremiah 33:17 out of context, which is mainly about the inevitable destruction of Jerusalem.

Comment: The promise regarding the natural throne was dependent on behavior and due to behavior there was a curse which was impossible to rescue. It then became clear that the eternal promise was that which would prevail since the eternal promise regards the world to come and not this present world. (Incidentally, this very subject makes it impossible for there to be a reign on earth for a thousand years, which would make a very cogent question on this site, hence an upvote +1 for this question.)